# Does the electrodynamics-like PDE $\epsilon^{ijk}\partial_j B_{kl}(x) = \delta^i_l\delta^{(3)}(x)$ have solutions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, differential-equations, magnetic-monopoles, dirac-string

Consider the following PDE in 3 dimensions
$$ \epsilon^{ijk}\partial_j B_{kl}(x) = \delta^i_l\delta^{(3)}(x)$$
Does $B_{kl}(x)$ have a solution? (It can have any kind of singularity, e.g. it can have singularity at the positive $z$ axis like a Dirac string emanating from the origin.)

Comment: Is $B_{kl}$ antisymmetric?

Comment: There is no such constraints

Comment: Then the eq. system decouples in 3 independent subsystems: $l=1$, $l=2$, & $l=3$.